# Why are custom Breadcrumb links all going to index page even though the href string seems correct?

Tags: php, href, silverstripe, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to generate custom Breadcrumbs in a SilverStripe app and I can't figure out why the links are not working. The HTML code in page source appears to be what I want and if I click on a link from the elements section of Safari's webpage inspector, I can land on the correct page. However, when I hover over the link or click on any of my Breadcrumb links in the browser page, I always see `localhost` and get directed to the homepage. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's some relevant code

My template, Breadcrumbs.ss:

```
<% loop $MyBreadcrumbs %>
  <a href="$url" title="$name">/ $name </a>
<% end_loop %>
```

The code below is HTML copied from Page Source. The links from this section all go to the root page, “/“, instead of, for example, "/resources/links/"

```
<div id="Breadcrumbs" class="grid_9 alpha">
    <a href="/" title="Home">/ Home </a>
    <a href="/resources/links/" title="Links">/ Links </a>
</div>
```

The links below all work and are generated using the `$Link` SilverStripe common variable:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-3 col-md-3 d-none d-md-block d-print-none">
        <ul class="aside__nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/resources/links/" title="Links">Links</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was due to the the lower margin on the element above, which was blocking access to the links that were displayed.